# How to ensure users can’t login to the system except with FTP?

Tags: login, ftp

How can I ensure that users can't login to the system except with FTP?

Comment: What Linux distribution? What FTP server?

Answer (score 3):

Create users with the `nologin` shell.

Then they will be able to authenticate to the FTP server with their username and password, but they won't be able to ssh or telnet in.

For example on a Fedora or Red Hat system:

```
# useradd -s /sbin/nologin username
# passwd username
<type the password>
```

Comment: Do not use FTP with "real" accounts! FTP sends all traffic ic clear text.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches to this, depending on your needs.

One is to set the shell to something not a shell, as described in another answer.

Another is to use [iptables](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=iptables&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CG0QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables&ei=h9SnT6yRNKaaiQe22qS4Aw&usg=AFQjCNG3Z3zEhV4N9YlWqAZOtDi193yabg&cad=rja) to set up a firewall that disallows all but FTP access.  If you want to make the server publicly accessible at all, I recommend this option, possibly in combination with the first.  You will need to enable *connection tracking* for it to work properly with FTP.